# Angular 5 take action on variable change

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do change detection.  I've got some HTML like so:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let element of elements">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="element.checked">
    </td>
    <td>
        <select [(ngModel)]="element.tag" (change)="tagChanged(element)" [disabled]="!element.checked">
```

When I uncheck the input field I want to force the element.tag value to be a certain value.   Should I just do an `(change)` attribute on the `input` like I did with the `select` or is there a better way?  The fact that I've bound the `ngModel` makes me wonder if I'm doing things the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(change)` event is bound to the input change event, which means that you can use this event even if you don't have a model bound to your input.

There is a second change event that Angular 5 provides (available as of Angular2).  That is the `(ngModelChange)` event.  It is the `@Output` of the `ngModel` directive. It fires when the model changes and cannot be used without ngModel and is used to listen to changes to what is bound to the `ngModel` on the element that it appears on.

You could do something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="element.checked"  (ngModelChange)="checkboxChanged($event)">

checkboxChanged(newValue) {
    //update element.tag based on new value
    //Since there is no two way binding...
    //Don't forget to update element.checked= newValue
}
```

The `(ngModelChange)` event is used to listen to changes to what is bound to the `ngModel` on the element that it appears on.  It is useful if you would like to do some manipulation on what your binding, like setting a string to uppercase etc.

```
<input [ngModel]="model.property"(ngModelChange)="modifyModelProperty($event)">
```

So,

```
<input [ngModel]="model.property" (ngModelChange)="model.property=$event">
```

Is equivalent to:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model.property">
```

> Thanks to @Sam Herrmann for posting link to docs
>   You can read more on this subject in the official docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel).

In your scenario use the `(change)` event since you are interested in a change in the state of your checkbox effecting something else in the model.  However, since `element.checked` is a `boolean`, instead of `[(ngModel)]` use  `[checked]="element.checked"` (Two way binding works a little slower than one way binding in theary :))

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="element.checked" (change)="reactToChange()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly bind to `[checked]` and `(change)` as @Azzi has pointed out, but what you may want to use is `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`. ngModel was designed to hide the details of which properties and events you need to bind to for the different types of form controls. The property and event for check-boxes are `checked` and `change` respectively, and for text inputs its `value` and `input` respectively. `ngModel` and `ngModelChange` on the other hand works on all inputs. You can read more on this subject in the official docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel).